# Setting up nginx expiry for certain static URL

Tags: nginx

My app are serving watermark images through an URL like this:

http://www.domain.com/watermark/image1234.jpg/thumbnail/

I'm wondering how do I set nginx to recognize this as static images so I could put Expiry header to them. So far I've tried the settings below in my nginx site config but doesn't work:

```
    location ~* \.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg|swf|ico)$ {
            access_log off;
            expires 30d;
            add_header Pragma public;
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
            tcp_nodelay off;
            break;
    }
```

and

```
    location ~* \.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg|swf|ico)\/[a-zA-Z0-9-]\/$ {
            access_log off;
            expires 30d;
            add_header Pragma public;
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
            tcp_nodelay off;
            break;
    }
```

The output I get:

```
$curl -I http://www.domain.com/watermark/image1234.jpg/thumbnail/
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Mon, 06 May 2013 12:33:51 GMT
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.23
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="phpThumb_generated_thumbnailjpg"
Last-Modified: Mon, 06 May 2013 09:52:52 GMT
```

No expiry in the header. Can anyone shows me the correct way?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I don't think your regex's will be matching anything, as they will only match files that are exactly `.png` - there is no space for a filename.

So they should be like:

```
location ~* /.+\.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg|swf|ico)$ {
    access_log off;
    expires 30d;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
    tcp_nodelay off;
    break;
}
```

and

```
location ~* /(.+)\.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg|swf|ico)\/[a-zA-Z0-9-]\/$ {
    access_log off;
    expires 30d;
    add_header Pragma public;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
    tcp_nodelay off;
    break;    
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The second one looks promising but I tried both and same output when curl the url.

Comment: Maybe post the complete nginx conf then?